# Unable to navigate the object structure and extract content of a json result

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to populate a list box with data from my database using an API call. I am having difficulties getting the data extracted from the result.

API call code:

```
[Route("api/GetStateOrProvinceListing")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<StateOrProvince>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetStateOrProvinceListing()
{
    BusinessLogicLayer_Generic _oBusinessLogicLayer_Generic = new BusinessLogicLayer_Generic();
    return Ok(_oBusinessLogicLayer_Generic.GetStateOrProvince().ToList());
}
```

The result I am getting from this when extracted in Chrome's console:

> [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

When I expand one of the objects, I get the following:

```
Abbreviation: "OK"
CountryOrRegionID: "3e45df44-319a-412f-902e-0b4b6c5bc5ad"
CreatedByID: "cea50dbc-1204-4e7f-9053-9b81f8a75add"
CreatedDateTime: "2015-02-03T00:55:51.353"
DisabledByID: null
DisabledDateTime: null
Enabled: true
ID: "d8088ea4-2a9b-46a6-8c4c-08a187dff2f8"
ModifiedByID: null
ModifiedDateTime: null
Name: "Oklahoma"
__proto__: Object
```

The HTML that is supposed to populate my list:

```
function populateStateFields() {
    callService("GET", g_WebServiceGetStateOrProvinceListingURL, null, function (jsonResult) {
        debugger;
        $(jsonResult).each(function () {
            $("<option />", {
                val: this.StateOrProvinceID,
                text: this.StateOrProvinceAbbreviation
            }).appendTo(listContactInformationStateAbbreviation);

            $("<option />", {
                val: this.StateOrProvinceID,
                text: this.StateOrProvinceAbbreviation
            }).appendTo(listLegalInformationStateAbbreviation);
        });
    });
}
```

Finally, the AJAX Call:

```
function callService(Type, Url, Data, successFunction) {
    $.ajax({
        type: Type,                     // GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: Url,                       // Location of the service
        data: Data,                     // Data sent to server
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFunction,
        error: serviceErrorHandler      // When Service call fails
    });
}
```

The result is a list of 75 blank entries. What do I need to do to get this to "parse" or navigate through my list?

Comment: The JSON you show does not contain the properties you want to read from it. So either `_oBusinessLogicLayer_Generic.GetStateOrProvince()` is returning the wrong type, or you're expecting properties to be there which there aren't.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thank you for pointing that it. It is always the simplest things. I changed the fields to ID and Abbreviation for the populate function and it works perfectly.